# python running batch file with administartor rights by subprocess to change ip

Tags: windows, python-3.x, ip, subprocess, windows-shell

I want to run a batch file which changes my ip address by static

// sth.bat

```
netsh int ip set address "Wifi" static xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx 255.255.255.0 xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.x 1
```

changing the ip address requires administrator rights so i want to use the subprocess module to run the file as admin

by the following python module

// ip_changer.py

```
import subprocess,time,socket
from subprocess import PIPE,STDOUT

p = subprocess.Popen("runas /user:Administrator \"C:/Users/userName/sth.bat\"", shell = True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
print(p.communicate(input = bytes("myPassword","utf-8")))
```

the communicate tuple returns me the following:

(b'Geben Sie das Kennwort f\x81r "Administrator" ein: \x00\r\n', None)

where the first entry is the question for the password from the shell, but my ip doesn't change at all.
Running the .bat file manually works fine.

Do i send the pasword before it is requested?
Or do you see what's wrong there ?

would be great to get some help here.

Comment: There's no way that can work. `runas.exe` won't read the password from a pipe, as a security measure. Out of the box, you can use ctypes to call `CreateProcessWithLogonW`, which is what `runas` uses. There are also 3rd party command-line tools that allow the password on the command line.

Comment: Hmm seems so ... Someone knows a way around ?

Comment: another way with subprocess :)

Comment: You can use subprocess to call Mark Russinovich's [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx).