# Running batch file as Administrator in python

Tags: python, subprocess, administrator

I'm tryng to run a batch file in python with administrator privileges using `runas` command.

My code is:

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(['runas', '/noprofile', '/user:Administrator', ' c:\windows\system32\addtask.bat'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
prog.stdin.write('mypass\n')
prog.stdin.flush()
output, error = prog.communicate()
if prog.returncode != 0: 
    print("FAILED: %d %s - %s" % (prog.returncode, output, error))
```

but it doesn't work. It outputs:

> FAILED: 1 Enter the password for Administrator: - none

I think there's something wrong passing the password through stdin.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can try to use psExec, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20803595/python-running-batch-file-with-administartor-rights-by-subprocess-to-change-ip

Comment: I guess you have to write a newline character to stdin after the password.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Even with newline doesn't work. I edited it.

Comment: @ErezBenHarush I'll give a try thank you

Comment: I think you simply cannot do that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107381/how-to-complete-the-runas-command-in-one-line/16116329

Comment: @luca.vercelli thank you, now it's clear. I will look for other ways....

Answer (score 2):

The question does not state if the password *must* be entered programmatically.

If you don't mind entering the password manually, via UAC prompt, you could run the bat file using [cmd.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), and use [`ShellExecuteW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecutew) to request elevation.

For example:

```py
from ctypes import windll

bat_file_path = 'c:\windows\system32\addtask.bat'  # from OP
result = windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(
    None,  # handle to parent window
    'runas',  # verb
    'cmd.exe',  # file on which verb acts
    ' '.join(['/c', bat_file_path]),  # parameters
    None,  # working directory (default is cwd)
    1,  # show window normally
)
success = result > 32
```